# Debugging into NuGet packages (again..) VS 2017

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2017, nuget, nuget-package

I am unable to step into NuGet packages (either hosted in a folder, or on a server - in my case MyGet) compiled with symbols when attempting to debug into a .NET Framework class library (in my case an nUnit test project). I have tried everything here -

[How to debug code in a nuget package created by me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44457552/how-to-debug-code-in-a-nuget-package-created-by-me)

To summarise what I have tried:

1) Compiling package with symbols, adding the folder containing the symbols.nupkg to the solution I'm debugging's Debug Source Files list. Adding the folder to the list in Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> Symbols. Tried 'load all modules' and 'load only specified modules'.

2) Enabling / Disabling 'Just My Code'

3) Manually copying the pdb files from the package project into my project's bin folder, no idea why this would still not work but it doesn't...

4) Adding the 'SourceLink.Create.CommandLine' package to my project.

5) Using a symbol source server (provided by MyGet)

EDIT: It appears that the debugger is using the versions in Temporary ASP.NET files, and only some have the PDB loaded for some reason. No matter what I use, symbol server, PDB files in the bin directory, it insists on only putting the DLL into Temp ASP.NET files.

[image: Random symbols]

All the DLLs here have been compiled with the 'Full' 'Debugging information' option, are not optimised, have the DEBUG/TRACE consts set, have the PDB inside the symbols.nupkg file - basically there is nothing special about the ones with the PDB in Temp ASP.NET versus the ones without :/

.snupkg is not an option for me as I'm using VS 2017.

Answer (score 2):

I finally got this to work with this process:

1) Set up MyGet as the NuGet and symbol server.

2) 'Just My Code' can be enabled.

3) 'Source server support' can be disabled.

4) Options -> Debugging -> Empty Symbol Cache.

5) Options -> NuGet -> Clear NuGet Cache

6) Restore packages, build and run.

This works consistently for me with MyGet, but not with locally hosted symbols (in a folder).

Answer (score 0):

> Debugging into NuGet packages (again..) VS 2017

If you are not deploy the symbol package to SymbolSource server, you could not step into your nuget package, even if you have added the symbols folder to the solution. That because Visual Studio could not parse `.pdb` file **in the nuget package**.

For some details info, you can check [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51675699/how-to-debug-a-nuget-package-without-wip-features-using-vs-15-7-and-above/51703447#51703447) about this issue.

And, as a **lightweight solution** to debug the nuget package, you can use following method:

[Is it possible to host both regular and symbols packages in a NuGet local feed on a network share?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45620764/is-it-possible-to-host-both-regular-and-symbols-packages-in-a-nuget-local-feed-o)

Besides, MS team create a new `.snupkg` extension which creates a streamlined package debugging experience for the entire NuGet ecosystem. You can check the document for some more info:

[NuGet Package Debugging & Symbols Improvements](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/wiki/NuGet-Package-Debugging-&-Symbols-Improvements)

Hope this helps.

Comment: I -have- had it working, but its like Russian roulette - I have not been able to get it to work today at all. .snupkg sounds promising... at the moment debugging is not really an option :(

Comment: On further examination (Debug->Modules), it appears that VS is attempting to load the PDB from Temporary ASP.NET files where only the DLL exists and claims it is optimised as well (it is not...!)