# Add source code for frameworks/NuGet packages to Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget

Given I am using framework via a NuGet package on my C# project inside Visual Studio and the source code for the framework/NuGet package is available e.g. on Github. How could I add the source code to Visual Studio, so I can browse it?

E.g. I write my own class deriving from a framework base class:

```
public MyClass : FrameworkClass
```

It compiles fine as all needed for that is given by the NuGet package. But in addition I now also want to be able to view the FrameworkClass implementation from inside Visual Studio.

Is that somehow possible, given the source code is available e.g. on Github? (it's ok for me to manually download the source code from Github and add it to Visual Studio in addition to the nuGet package, I just don't know if and how that can be done)

Comment: If the source code is written in a .Net language, you can import the Project(s). You don't need the NuGet package(s) anymore.

Comment: 1.As Jimi said, since we can download the project from github to local machine. You can choose to import the project(which contains the source code) into current solution(right-click solution=>import existing ...), and then `right-click  your current project=>add reference=>add project reference` to reference that downloaded project. This has no difference than using nuget package, and it will bring the ability to view source code directly.   2. In VS code editor, you can type F12 in one method(function) to navigate to the line where the function is defined.

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT I think your option for decompiling comes from Resharper. Also decompiling likely doesn't give the exact same source code / misses comments etc. at all: I want to continue to use the NuGet packages, so my project can also easily be build in the cloud (currently developing a Xamarin application which is also compiled on App Center which downloads all dependencies using NuGet)

Comment: VS now includes [this function](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/go-to-and-peek-definition?view=vs-2019#view-decompiled-source-definitions-instead-of-metadata-c) itself even in VS2019 community version. And yes, the decompiling is not always accurate, sorry for the bad idea :(  And if you want to view source code during debugging your project, you can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21857780/how-to-debug-into-my-nuget-package-deployed-from-teamcity/58565483#58565483), if you want to view source code when developing current project... Maybe not supported...

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT Please post as answer. Besides that I am lucky that the nuget package I am mainly interested in seems to support sourcelink, I guess there isn't any other way anyways. And the debugging thing is cool, didn't know about that :-)

Comment: typo, meant decompiling, not debugging.

Answer (score 2):

As I know VS doesn't have the option to support `viewing source code` of one nuget package directly in one project that consumes that package. At least during `developing time`(when code in text editor), this is not supported.

But if someone wants to `navigate to and view source code` of one nuget package during `debugging` time:

1.One way I once used is to put `.pdb` file into nuget package, and download the source files in one folder, add path of folder to `Debug Source Files` setting.

2.Another way is to use [Source Link+ nuget](https://github.com/dotnet/sourcelink/) way, it's supported in VS2017 and VS2019.

For more details please refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21857780/how-to-debug-into-my-nuget-package-deployed-from-teamcity/58565483#58565483), and there's some other good workarounds there. Cheers!

Comment: hmm, I made a mistake - actually source link is great for debugging, but yeah, I want to be able to explore source code without debugging. My fault and I guess I rashed my own questions asking you to post an answer. Let's see if anyone else replies, otherwise I will accept your answer and ask a new one especially for really only browsing.

Comment: Any update feel free to share here :)  And if you find the workaround youself, consider adding it as answer to share the useful info!