# Debug Nuget Library

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, symbols, nuget-server

I have a set of Nuget Libraries that I compile and modify myself.

I build them without publishing on any Nuget server. (**It is not my library**)

On the other side, I have a project that use such Nugets, but I wish to debug them...

In the best situation I wish to:

- use my local .dll and .pdb
- debug by using local .pdb and (updated) source code

I'm looking for the best possible solution, if possible by loading all local symbols,
but I'm not sure it is possible.

Maybe I have to build on my own local Nuget server and use a local Symbol server too, but it looks overkill?

Comment: I wouldn't say **_overkill_**, but it is a bit of a **stretch.**

Comment: I have a question - **What do you mean by** "It is not my library)"**?** You said you had multiple **Nuget** libraries, yet now it sounds like you **only have one.**

Comment: For your own local packages, your only hope is to configure a symbol folder and drop the symbol files in it for VS to pick up. The local NuGet feed and local symbol folder are equivalent to the remote servers if you don't want to set up real servers. However, you should notice that one stop solutions like https://loic-sharma.github.io/BaGet/ are not any harder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Maybe I have to build on my own local Nuget server and use a local
>   Symbol server too, but it looks overkill?

As far as l know, when you want to debug a nuget library in a new project, you must add the required `nuget.pdb` and related `xxx.cs` source files in the new project.

According to your description, the nuget package is created by yourself which is more easiler to realize it:

**1)** If you have the **nuget.pdb** file  and the corresponding **cs** file on the local, you just need to put the **PDB** file in the output file of the project which references the nuget, and then right-click on the **Solution**-->`Properties`-->`Common Properties`-->`Debug Source Files`-->to add the folder path which the cs files exist into it.

[image]

**2)** If you do not have the current `nuget.pdb` file  and related cs source files for debugging on the local, you need to include these files in `nuget.nupkg` when creating the nuget package by using [nuget.exe cli with `xxx.nuspec`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package), so that these files can be added to the current agent when you install the nuget package.

**Note:**This is the special steps for creating your nuget package:

**A)** please make sure that you have downloaded the nuget.exe and then set its path to environment variables so that it can be called in CMD. You can refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/install-nuget-client-tools#nugetexe-cli).

**B)** Open CMD, type cd xxxxxx(the path of the project which contains `xxxx.csproj`)

**C)** type `nuget spec` to generate the `xxx.spec` file

[image]

Then open it and add like these:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
   ........
  </metadata>
<files>
<file src="bin\Debug\ClassLibrary11.pdb" target="lib\target framework version (like net472 or netstandard2.0)" />------ClassLibrary11.pdb is the nuget.pdb
 <file src="Class1.cs" target="src" />------Class1.cs is the source file
</files>
</package>
```

**D)** then type `nuget pack` to generate the nuget package which contains these debug files.

**E)** when you install this nuget package in a new project, please do not forget to [clean the nuget cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders#clearing-local-folders) first. After that, you should add the path of the resource files into `Debug Source Files`.(the resource files exists in the `C:\Users\xxx\.nuget\packages\package name\src` or `C:\xxxxx\ConsoleApp(project folder)\packages\package name\src`)

**Edit**

**F)** When you start debugging it, please do not forget to disable `Just My Code` In `Tools`-->`Options`-->`Debugging`-->`General`-->uncheck `Enable Just My Code`.

Also, you can consider [source links](https://github.com/dotnet/sourcelink/blob/master/README.md) as source control so that you won't configure the source path by Solution=>properties.

**In addition**, you can refer to [this similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21857780/how-to-debug-into-my-nuget-package-deployed-from-teamcity).