# Nuget .symbols.package upon install doesn't contain pdb's and installs only dll's- VS 2019

Tags: nuget, visual-studio-2019

I have nuget package with symbols - "Mypackage.symbols.nuget" and has dll and pdb files.

I created a local repository for testing and installed this "Mypackage.symbols.nuget" but after installing i see only dll file present in nuget folder under users directory and pdb is missing.

i tried a tweak by renaming the file manually to "Mypackage.nuget" from "Mypackage.symbols.nuget" and then i tried to install i see both dll and pdb is present after i installed.

Why does not pdb is getting downloaded when i have .symbols.nuget as i need to symbols package with dll and pdb for debugging purpose.

i created nuget package upon csproj property group.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Mypackage.symbols.nuget` is not a package in the form of being installed, and does not have the conditions for being installed. The purpose of this form of package is to publish to `nuget.org` together with `nuget.nupkg`. Usually, you should push the `Mypackage.symbols.nupkg` file into `https://nuget.smbsrc.net/`.

**Before this,** you should also push the `Mypackage.nupkg` into **nuget.org**(`https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json`).

**And** then input the **symbolsource.org**(`https://nuget.smbsrc.net/`) into **VS Symbol Server**.

**In this case,** you could install the published `Mypackage.nupkg` package  from the `nuget.org` and then it will match the related `Mypackage.symbols.nupkg` on the `symbolsource.org` so that you can debug the content of the nuget.

[image]

You can refer to [this document about creating legacy symbol packages(.symbols.nupkg)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/symbol-packages).

=============================================================

All of the above need to push these packages into `nuget.org`. And in the local, you should use that way. And  `Mypackage.symbols.nupkg` is not an installed package for any projects.

**To prove this**, you can try these:

**1)** in my side, I add these node in csproj file to create the symbol package.

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <IncludeSymbols>true</IncludeSymbols>
</PropertyGroup>
```

[image]

**Then**, config the local path of it into nuget package source. After that, delete the `xxx.nupkg` directly,

[image]

**I am sure that** nuget package UI cannot find the package under the local path which proves the `Mypackage.symbols.nupkg` is not an installed nuget package and only be uploaded into the server.

**Solution**

**1)** just rename the `Mypackage.symbols.nupkg` as `Mypackage.nupkg` since it has the `dll` and `pdb` files.

**2)** use this csproj node to repack your project.

```
 <ItemGroup>
     <None Include="$(OutputPath)$(AssemblyName).pdb" Pack="true" PackagePath="lib\$(TargetFramework)"></None>
 </ItemGroup>
```

And the main `xxx.nupkg` will contain the pdb file.

**3)** also use this xml node in csproj file:

```
<PropertyGroup>        
<AllowedOutputExtensionsInPackageBuildOutputFolder>$(AllowedOutputExtensionsInPackageBuildOutputFolder);.pdb</AllowedOutputExtensionsInPackageBuildOutputFolder>        
</PropertyGroup>
```

**Note**: if you want to debug the nuget package locally, you should also pack the resource files into the nupkg file.

[See this thread answered by me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62925530/debugging-nuget-package-locally/62946435#62946435).

**In addition**, [using Debugging information: Embedded format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63562527/embedding-debugging-information-to-the-build-does-not-include-any-debugging-symb/63571646#63571646) might be much easier.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Also i found one more way to have nuget package with pdb's and we need to add this node to propertygroup - <AllowedOutputExtensionsInPackageBuildOutputFolder>$(AllowedOutputExtensionsInPackageBuildOutputFolder);.pdb</AllowedOutputExtensionsInPackageBuildOutputFolder>