# Embedding debugging information to the build does not include any debugging symbols

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget

In my project, in the Build - Advanced section I've set "Debugging information: Embedded":

[image: setting embedded debug info]

Also, I have set an option to package my project as nupkg file.

[image: setting create package]

As the project has built there is a nupkg file created, but when I use this nupkg file upon debugging another project there are no symbols included, nor PDB file is included inside of nupkg file.

My questions: as far as I understand I have to do different steps to include PDB file into my nupkg. In this case, what is the purpose of "Debugging information: Embedded" option, why it is available and what does it do? Because no debugging information is included in the result package file even this option is enabled.

Thank you.

Comment: You may check this question [Include pdb files into my nuget (nupkg) files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41713693/include-pdb-files-into-my-nuget-nupkg-files)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Embedding debugging information to the build does not include any
> debugging symbols

`Debugging information: Embedded` means that **MSBuild** will embed the **PDB** file directly into the target **DLL**, meaning that the DLL not only contains its own DLL but also contains the contents of the PDB file. A **DLL** already contains two contents: itself and the `pdb` file.

> As the project has built there is a nupkg file created, but when I use
> this nupkg file upon debugging another project there are no symbols
> included, nor PDB file is included inside of nupkg file.

**So you do not have to worry about missing the pdb file, it is already be put into the DLL.**

And if you want to debug the nuget package's content locally in another project, you should only pack the source files(`cs files`) into nuget package.

**1)** Add such pack nodes in your lib project.

```
<ItemGroup>
        <Compile Update="Class1.cs" Pack="true" PackagePath="SourceFiles"></Compile>

        //add any source files like this if you want to debug their functions
</ItemGroup>
```

It will pack the source files into a folder called **SourceFiles** of the nupkg.

[image]

[image]

The **purpose** is to package the source file along with nuget so that the source file can be directly taken out of the package for subsequent debugging to ensure successful debugging.

**2)** then pack the project, before you install this new version of the package into the project, you should first **uninstall** the old one, [clean nuget caches](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders#clearing-local-folders) or just delete all files under `C:\Users\xxx(current user)\.nuget\packages`, then install the new one.

**3)** Before you debug the project, you should first add the source files of the nuget in to the solution.**Otherwise**, VS will report an error that the nuget source file cannot be found when debugging.

Right-click on the solution-->**Properties**-->**Common Properties**-->**Debug Source Files**

input the **SourceFiles** folder of the nuget into it:

[image]

**In addition**, there is [a similar issue about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60247078/debug-nuget-library/60283327#60283327).

This is a sample about my test:

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to change the default value of the Debug symbols option? Like normally the default option is **PDB file, portable across all platforms** can you change that for example to **Embedded in DLL/EXE, portable across all platforms**, so for every new Project this is now the default?