# How can I debug using a nuget symbols package from a local folder?

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, debug-symbols, symbol-server

I have a folder on my server that hosts my nuget packages. These packages do not contain source code or symbols (PDBs). This works well.

Recently I have set up another folder on my local server to host the symbols files from the assemblies in my nuget packages.

I have added the path to the symbols folder to visual studio and when I place the PDB files in the folder they are loaded correctly in VS and I am able to step into the code when debugging. If I look at the symbol load information in VS I can see that the PDB was downloaded from the symbols folder on my server, confirming that everything is working correctly.

I believe the preferred way to do this sort of thing is to have nuget create a symbols package at the same time as creating the nuget package and I would like to move to this way of working.

Creating the symbols and nuget package is not an issue. The issue is that when I push (using nuget) the symbols package to my symbols folder VS is not able to use it. When I try to step into my nuget package VS tries to find the PDB and I can see that it looks in my symbols folder but it can not find the PDB, which makes sense because it is contained inside a nuget symbols package.

Can anyone explain what I am missing?

Answer (score 8):

> How can I debug using a nuget symbols package from a local folder?

AFAIK, you could not use local folder as symbol server, I tried it before and it didn't work, got the same error as you. That because the `.pdb` file is wrapped in the symbol **package**, Visual Studio could not access `.pdb` file directly in the symbol package.

You should [setup your own SymbolServer](https://www.xavierdecoster.com/post/2012/08/07/setting-up-your-own-symbolsource-server-step-by-step.html) or [upload it to symbolsource.com](http://www.symbolsource.org/Public/Home/VisualStudio), after you setup SymbolServer and upload nuget's with symbols, you must configure [Visual Studio debugger](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/314186/How-to-use-symbol-server-and-why-you-really-like-t).

**Besides**, if you do not want to setup your own SymbolServer or upload it to symbol server, there is a **lightweight solution** here:

1. [Put the pdb and source code file in the NuGet package alongside the dll](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/symbol-packages#referring-to-files-in-the-nuspec).
2. Add the source code to the Debug Source Files for the solution that references the package (*right click on Solution, select Properties...Common Properties...Debug Source Files, and add the root source directory for the relevant binary reference.*)

Please refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45620764/is-it-possible-to-host-both-regular-and-symbols-packages-in-a-nuget-local-feed-o) for more details on step 1 and step 2, .

Then you can debugging this nuget package with a local folder:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello Leo, Unfortunately neither of your workarounds are very practical for me. Currently the only solution does seem to be to setup your own symbols server. I have reported this issue to Microsoft and they are investigating it. Here is the link in case you'd like to up vote it! https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/238550/nuget-symbols-package-not-understood-by-vs.html