# How to use breakpoint for debugging in other solution

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-debugging

I have a web application in .netcore, I have two Solution and from one of them I have just a class library and create nuget package from that, from another solution I used that nuget package in it and call some methods but how can I use breakpoint for debugging methods in that class library?

Comment: This will probably be useful: https://geeklearning.io/how-to-debug-a-net-core-nuget-package/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Debugging private NuGet packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12739662/debugging-private-nuget-packages)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can used this `Debugger.Break()` in your method and when call that method its stop on this line and you can debug it, use this one:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
```